# If condition, load table view else load web view xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiwebview

I have a View Controller.

Within this view controller I have a menu and a tab bar depending on what menu item is clicked.

Depending on what is clicked in the menu/the tab bar. I want to load either a `UIWebView` or a `UITableView` with data.

I have already added a `UIWebView` to the view controller. But I'm unsure whether it is "Good Practise" to do a condition as follows:

"If this particular page needs a `UITableView`" - hide the `UIWebView` and load the table view cells.

&

"If this particular page needs a `UIWebView`" - hide the `UITableView` and load the web data.

Noting that down, it doesn't seem so bad.

What do you think? Can anyone offer me a solution?

Here is a shot of the storyboard atm:

[image: storyboard view controller]

and here is the code that i'm using to determine if my page needs a `UIWebView` or a `UITableView`:

```
NSString * title = self.learnfestTitle;
Defaults * def = [[Defaults alloc]init]; //NSLog(@"Tag: %d",tag);

if([title isEqualToString:@"My Festival"]){
    switch (tag) {
        case 0:
            //my planner
            [self.learnfestWebView loadHTMLString:@"my planner" baseURL:nil];
            break;
        case 1:
            //my notes
            [self.learnfestWebView loadHTMLString:@"my notes" baseURL:nil];
            break;
        case 2:
            //my profile
            [self.learnfestWebView loadHTMLString:@"my profile" baseURL:nil];
            break;
    }
}
```

TIA

Comment: I think you should ask this question at codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @M.Othman Please [take a tour](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) and [read the help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) before you continue to make recommendations to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help).  Just because someone is asking about best practice doesn't make the question a good fit for CR.  We require real code from a real project that is already working exactly as the user intends, not a small snippet of hypothetical code cludged together just for the sake of asking how to do something masked as a question about best practice.

Comment: @M.Othman Notice, the [Code Review version of this question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/90056/36366)  has been closed as off-topic.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong recommendation Chris, @nhgrif thanx for ur comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is bad practise at all. Sure there's probably going to be someone that comes up with a better way technically but this seems the way to go to ensure better user experience so that the webview isn't reloading every time the user want's to see it

Comment: Because you are the only one who has offered to help. I've kept going and i've achieved what I intended to do. It involved setting the webview to hidden when I want my table view to show and vice versa. Thanks for the input. Heres a snippet of code: `if([title isEqualToString:@"Have Your Say"]){
        switch (tag) {
            case 0:
                self.learnfestTableView.hidden = YES;
                [self.learnfestWebView loadHTMLString:@"feedback form" baseURL:nil];
                self.learnfestWebView.hidden = NO;
                break;
        }
    }`